# Пытаюсь получить токен для юмани, попробовал через ноду, выводит ошибку Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (at auth.html:17:71)

Tags: node.js, яндекс-касса

```
<script>
const needle = require("needle") // Подключаем Needle для запросов.
const clientId = "" // Создаем константу с нашим client_id.


const scopes = [
    "account-info"
]

const postDataAuthorize = {
    client_id: clientId,
    response_type: "code",
    redirect_uri: "ури",
    scope: scopes
}

needle.post('https://yoomoney.ru/oauth/authorize', postDataAuthorize, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }, (err, resp) => {
    console.log(resp.body) // выводим ответ.
})
</script>
```

Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (at auth.html:17:71)

Ошибка, собственно в это строке :

```
needle.post('https://yoomoney.ru/oauth/authorize', postDataAuthorize, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }, (err, resp) => {
    console.log(resp.body) // выводим ответ.
})
```

Comment: `, { headers: {...} }`